# Using jquery and thymeleaf how do I create dynamic buttons each with their own event listener

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

My goal is to build a dynamic FAQ page where the questions are visible, and when you click on the said question the div with the answer would appear. Once you click the div again it would toggle again.
I've tried a few things and the best result I've accomplished was toggling the first question's answer regardless of what question was clicked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <link href="./img/favicon.png" rel="shortcut icon"/>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta content="width=1280, maximum-scale=1.0" name="viewport"/>
    <link  th:href="@{css/faq.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <link  th:href="@{css/faq-new.css}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
</head>
<body style="margin: 0;
 background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 1.0);">
<input id="anPageName" name="page" type="hidden" value="faq"/>
<div class="faq">
    <th:block th:insert="_header.html :: header"></th:block>
    <div class="rectangle2">
    </div>
    <div class="justaskus">
        Just Ask Us
    </div>

    <!-------========= FAQ =========------------->
    <div class="faq-container">
        <div class="th-start" th:block th:each="faqType, stats : ${faqTypeDaoList}">
            <div class="q-type-wrapper">
                <div class="type-header">
                    <h4 th:text="${faqType.faqTypeName}"></h4>
                </div>

                <!----========= Question ========--------->
                <div class="th-wrap" th:each="question, stat: ${faqTypeDaoList[_${stats.index}_].faqList}">

                    <a href="#">
                        <div id="box" class="question-box">
                            <div class="bullet"></div>
                            <img th:src="@{img/artboard-copy-3-unnamed-3@2x.png}" class="arrow"/>
                            <img th:src="@{img/artboard-copy-3-unnamed-13@2x.png}" class="unnamed" style="display:none;"/>
                            <div class="questions" th:text="${faqTypeDaoList[_${stats.index}].faqList[${stat.index}_].question}"></div>
                            <div id="answers" class="dropdown-answer" th:text="${faqTypeDaoList[_${stats.index}].faqList[${stat.index}_].answer}"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#box').on("click", ()=> {
            $(this).children[3].toggle();
        });


    });
</script>
```

That is my current code and it does absolutely nothing. Here are a few attempts I took

```
/* One attempt */
$('.questions').on("click",function(){
        // "this" in $(this) --> means the current clicked element
        // .find() will search the CHILDREN of the clicked element with the class "sub-nav"
        $(this).find("dropdown-answer").toggle();
      });

/* Another attempt. This one toggled only the first question's answer regardless if what button was clicked. */
var click = document.getElementById("dropdown-answer");
    if(click.style.display === "none") {
        click.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        click.style.display = "none";
    }
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

`find()` will find children inside the element you provide (so in this case you put `this` in it so `.questions`) but your `.dropdown-answer` is not a child of that element.

you can write it like this

```
$(this " + .dropdown-answer").toggle();
```

Or place the element inside the `.questions` element and get it like this

```
$(this).find(".dropdown-answer").toggle();
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I've already tried this and it does not work.

Comment: Could you edit your html so that it is pure html for testing?

Comment: Yes I can. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Well if you post the html without your framework code I can play around with it and find the solution for it.

Comment: So I got it working, but because there are some bootstraps styling display: none is not working. is there a way to use jquery to change css?

Comment: Ive been trying to use this to change the visibility: if($(this).find(".dropdown-answer").css("visibility") == "hidden"){
            $(this).find(".dropdown-answer").css("visibility", "visible");
        }
        else {
            $(this).find(".dropdown-answer").css("visibility", "hidden");
        }

Comment: I can't really help you without a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example